# Why does regex in python not properly detect my string delimiters?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to write a program that can take any recipe made in WPRM (wordpress recipe maker) and automatically rescale it. It is supposed to take the HTML code of the print version of such a recipe (see for example [this cookie recipe](https://handletheheat.com/wprm_print/30199)) and extract the relevant information (amount, unit, name) for each ingredient using regular expressions. The relevant parts are enclosed by something along the lines of ...ingredient-attribute"> and . However, this  sometimes is not recognized.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
ingredients = re.split(r'<li', recipestr_cut) 
    
    for x in ingredients:
        
        out = [] # initialize a single element of the recipe as a list
        
        amount_m = re.search(r'ingredient-amount"\>(.+)\<\/span>', x)
        if amount_m:
            out.append(amount_m.group(1))
        unit_m = re.search(r'ingredient-unit"\>(.+)\<\/span>', x)
        if unit_m:
            out.append(unit_m.group(1))
        ingredient_m = re.search(r'ingredient-name"\>(.+)\<\/span>', x)
        if ingredient_m:
            out.append(ingredient_m.group(1))
        
        if len(out) > 0:
            recipe_readable.append(out)
```

For the recipe in the example before, this works neatly and returns

```
[['3', 'cups', '(380 grams) all-purpose flour'], ['1', 'teaspoon', 'baking soda'], ['1', 'teaspoon', 'fine sea salt'], ['2', 'sticks (227 grams) unsalted butter, at cool room temperature (67°F)'], ['1/2', 'cup', '(100 grams) granulated sugar'], ['1 1/4', 'cups', '(247 grams) lightly packed light brown sugar'], ['2', 'teaspoons', 'vanilla'], ['2', 'large eggs, at room temperature'], ['2', 'cups', '(340 grams) semisweet chocolate chips']]
```

However, if one instead uses a somewhat more complicated recipe, for example [this pork bun recipe](https://thewoksoflife.com/wprm_print/31141), it apparently no longer recognizes the `</span>` delimiter, because the output looks like this:

```
[['2/3</span>&#32;<span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-unit">cup</span>&#32;<span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-name">heavy cream', 'cup</span>&#32;<span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-name">heavy cream</span>&#32;<span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-notes wprm-recipe-ingredient-notes-faded">(at room temperature)', ...
```

Which clearly includes the `</span>`, and also does not seem to split the string in the right places. Instead, I would expect something like

```
[['2/3','cup','heavy cream'],...
```

How could this be fixed? I have only very recently learned about regular expressions, so this is still scary to me.

Comment: Obligatory link: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). The site you linked to has elements with semantically-named classes, so it shouldn't be too hard to query them using CSS selector or XPath.

Comment: You need to at least use non-greedy regexp: `.*?`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regex, use an HTML parser, like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_ingredients_info_from_html(html):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

  ingredients = []
  class_name = 'wprm-recipe-ingredient'

  for ingredient in soup.select(f'.{class_name}'):
    record = dict.fromkeys(['amount', 'unit', 'name', 'notes'])

    for info in record:
      element = ingredient.select_one(f'.{class_name}-{info}')

      if element:
        record[info] = element.text
    
    ingredients.append(record)

  return ingredients
```

Try it:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://thewoksoflife.com/wprm_print/31141'

print(get_ingredients_info_from_html(requests.get(url).content))

'''
[
    {
        'amount': '2/3',
        'unit': 'cup',
        'name': 'heavy cream',
        'notes': '(at room temperature)'
    },
    {
        'amount': '1',
        'unit': 'cup',
        'name': 'milk',
        'notes': '(whole milk preferred, but you can use 2%, at room 
temperature)'
    },
    ...
]
'''
```

Comment: What would happen if `wprm-recipe-ingredient-amount` were missing in the record ? Would the other record elements populate ? In the html, each record is contained within it's `<li class="wprm-recipe-ingredient"` .. `</li>` tags. I'm not an html expert but if a record element is missing what's to stop it from going outside of this record to find the next available element ?

Comment: @sln I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. `record`'s values are default to `None`. If an element is not found, the `if element:` block won't run and the corresponding value remain `None`. `.select_one()` (and `.select()`, for that matter) only return descendants of the node it's called on, so other `<li>`s' info wouldn't mess with the current one's.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you said except for `other <li>s' info wouldn't mess with the current one`. Which was my question. If I ever try to do this I still won't know how. In fact that didn't explain anything.

Comment: @sln Given this HTML (class name changed for simplicity): `<li class="l"><span class="amount">1</span><span class="unit">teasppon</span><span class="name">olive oil</span><li class="l"><span class="amount">3</span></li>`. If I has the first `<li>` element in a variable called `li`, `li.select_one('.amount')` would either return `<span class="amount">1</span>` (this exact element) or `None`. It's just how the API works.

Comment: This works, but for some reason returns every element three times? looks like this:
`[{'amount': '3', 'unit': 'cups', 'name': '(380 grams) all-purpose flour', 'notes': None}, {'amount': '3', 'unit': 'cups', 'name': '(380 grams) all-purpose flour', 'notes': None}, {'amount': '3', 'unit': 'cups', 'name': '(380 grams) all-purpose flour', 'notes': None},...`

Comment: @paulina You are talking about [this page](https://handletheheat.com/wprm_print/30199), correct? I re-ran the code on my local machine and it seems to work correctly (no duplicates). Perhaps you were using the function incorrectly?

Comment: @InSync i literally copypasted what you posted. the only changes i made was the link to the cookie recipe, and to move the `import requests` line to the top. the same thing happens to me with the pork bun recipe

Comment: @paulina Does your code look *exactly* like [this](https://replit.com/@SyncIn/SOq76202466) (click `<>` to see the file)?

Comment: @InSync it does indeed look exactly like this. it also happens both in spyder and the ubuntu console

Comment: @paulina I use neither Spyder nor Ubuntu so I'm sorry that I can't really help you out. Try using a cloud-based platform or post a new question then.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

When you have multiple ingredients on one line of the string, (which is legal HTML) this regex becomes ambiguous:

```
ingredient-amount"\>(.+)\<\/span>
```

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/lbtuUz/1)

It could match this:

```
ingredient-amount">2/3</span>
```

but it could also match this:

```
ingredient-amount">2/3</span>&#32;<span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-unit">cup</span>
```

The way it resolves this ambiguity is to choose the longest match. This is called greedy matching.

#### Solution #1

You want it to match in a lazy way, and match as few characters as possible. This is a lazy match. Example:

```
ingredient-amount"\>(.+?)\<\/span>
```

#### Solution #2

The previous way will work, but my preferred solution is to make it so that the "match anything" part of the regex won't skip over any span tags. That would look like this:

```
ingredient-amount"\>([^<]+)\<\/span>
```

This changes the "match anything" part to "match anything but <"

I like this kind of solution because it's easier to debug.